# upload multiplos

Tags: php

Olá pessoal estou desenvolvendo um site, porém ainda sou um pouco leiga e um amigo meu estava me ajudando, porém agora não dá mais para ele me ajudar.

Bom minha duvida é o seguinte como faço para fazer o upload de mais de uma imagem pois este sistema que ele montou para mim da para fazer upload de uma e uma imagem, e isso demoraria muito para o cliente.

**Código php:**

```
<form method="post" style="margin-left: 400px;" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="queue"></div>
    <input name="imagem" type="file">
    <input type="submit" name="up" value="upado">
</form>
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['up']) && $_POST['up'] == "upado") {
        if (count($_FILES) > 0) {
            $img = $_FILES['imagem'];
            $ff = md5(sha1($img['name'])).".jpg";
            if (move_uploaded_file($img['tmp_name'], "../fotos/".$ff)) {
                $sql  = "insert into imoveis_fotos (foto_imovel,foto_nome)";
                $sql .=" values ({$imv_id},'{$ff}')";
                mysql_query($sql);

                header("refresh:1;url=?pag=imoveis_fotos&id=".$imv_id);
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Acho que será de maior valia você buscar aprender como funciona o código para tentar alterá-lo por si mesmo do que nós o alterarmos para você. A ideia é simples: crie vários campos do tipo arquivo com `name=imagem[]`, assim no PHP você possuirá todos os aquivos em `$_FILES`, repetindo esta mesma lógica da pergunta para cada um deles.

Comment: Obrigada, estou dando uma pesquisada acho que consegui

Comment: Vê se ajuda: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Comment: obrigada pela ajuda pessoal, consegui